# Server collapses when memory reaches 88%

Tags: server, monitoring, digital-ocean, pm2, angular-universal

I'm using server side rendering with Angular universal, and PM2 as the process manager, in a Digital Ocean droplet of 8 GB Memory / 80 GB Disk / Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64 / 4 vCPUs.

I use a 6GB swap file, and the available memory when "free -m" is the following:

```
          total    used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       7983    1356        5290          16        1335        6278
Swap:      6143      88        6055
```

The [ram used](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) looks fine. There are 4 processes with Cluster Mode of PM2.

Every 6-8 hours, when the memory reaches ~88% in my Digital Ocean panel, the CPU goes very high, the web application does not respond correctly and PM2 has to restart the process, not sure for how long the web application does not work well.

Here is an image of what happens:

[image: CPU and Memory of the server]

Performance is fine when working normally:

[image: Web application performance]

I think I'm missing some sort of configuration or something, since this happens always at the same periods of time.

**EDIT1** So far I fixed some incompatibilities in my code (the app was working, but sometimes failed due to this), and added a [memory limit in pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/#max-memory-restart) of 1GB. I'm not sure if this is the way to go since I'm a bit new to process management, but the CPU levels are fine now. Any comment is appreciated. I leave a picture of the current behaviour, every time one of the four processes reach 1GB, its restarted:

[image]

**EDIT2** I add 3 more images, 2 showing top processes from Digital Ocean, and one showing Keymetrics status:

[image: Memory top processes]
[image: CPU top processes]
[image: Keymetrics processes]

**EDIT3** I figured out some memory leaks from my Angular app (I forgot to unsubscribe from a couple of subscriptions) and the system behaviour improved, but the memory line is still going up. I'll keep investigating about memory leaking in Angular and see if I've made some other mistakes:

[image: Memory RAM edit3]

Comment: Can you see if there is anything useful in `/var/log/messages`? Do you see the process getting Out of Memory (OOM) killed by the system? And which application is using the CPU when the restart happens?

Comment: I don't have that file in /var/log, but in kernel.log and syslog I only have "[UFW BLOCK]" messages. The process that get out of memory (from the digital ocean Top Processes) is: "node /var/www/name-of-the-app". I attach 3 more images: top processes from digital ocean and Keymetrics panel

Comment: is it "normal" that the memory restarts often?

Comment: No, it's definitely not normal. Look into "Angular Universal" and memory leaks, maybe that'll yield something.

Comment: Thank you, I think the problem comes from "Angular memory leaks". I didn't unsubscribe from a couple of subscriptions. Now that I did it's better, but the memory line keeps going up, I've updated the post with another image. I'll give you the reward since you pointed out the problem, but could you tell me if you know any source where I can learn about this? or any information about what should be the expected memory behaviour and when should I upgrade the server? I couldn't find any information related to "Memory normal behaviour". The line should be always horizontal, with some ups and downs?

Comment: This is a pretty good source: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/. But I just realised that it might be because of a third party dependency "angularfire2", which is not 100% ready yet for Angular Universal. I'll update in any case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Angular Universal app is leaking memory, it should not increase over time as you observe but stay mostly flat.

You can try to find the memory leak (looks like you already found an issue and have a suspicion what else it could be).

Another thing you can try is periodically restart your app.
See [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1076) for example how to restart your pm2 process every couple of hours to reset and prevent the OOM situation that you've been running into.

Answer (score 0):

In our (edge) case, the kubernetes healthcheck was the cause of the issue. The healthcheck accessed the main page by an internal IP. The page used the caller URL (in this case its IP) to load some resources which it couldn't find that way. This lead to an error and was somehow cached and slowly used up all memory. We had the same very linear rise in memory even during nights because of the regularity of the healthcheck.

We solved the problem by letting the healthcheck call "/health" where we only return a 200 code.. as one should do anyway.